# What's the corresponding C++ native type of C++/CLI System::String^

Tags: c++-cli

I need to rewrite a C++/CLI project to native C++ project, by removing or replacing managed codes. I'm not very familiar with C++/CLI，so, what's the corresponding C++ native type of C++/CLI `System::String^`, is it `std::string` or `std::string*`?

For example a C++/CLI function `Foo(System::String^ location)`, rewrite it to `Foo(std::string location)`，is this right?

Comment: The closest match is `std::wstring` (because `System.String` is an UTF-16 string and `std::wstring` is an UTF-16 string in C++ when targeting Windows). Formally `^` is not a pointer (`*`) nor a reference (`&`) but a handle (and because .NET strings are immutable you could imagine it as `const std::wstring&`). My best advice? Do not translate 1:1 from C++/CLI, best practices and idioms are pretty different. Also note that if that C++/CLI code was intended as an interface with other .NET applications then you can't use STL types (and you need to go back to `wchar_t*`).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's probably `std::string` though it depends on your ownership intentions. For example, the closest translation of String^ (ignoring the shared memory part for the moment) would be a `std::string&` which is known as a `reference` - effectively a pointer except they are never null and cannot be manually de-allocated. A class is more likely to have `std::string` members (meaning that it owns that data) than `std::string&` members (meaning it does not own that data)

The other question for function signatures is whether `Foo` is allowed to mutate the `location` object. If it isn't, a `const std::string&` parameter should be used

It's probably not `std::string*` as 'raw pointers' are quite rare to use in modern C++. You generally create objects on the stack and pass them around using references, allowing RAII to manage the memory - I would definitely read up more on RAII which explains the ownership model and is very important for writing C++